Using home EV charge point to power Christmas decorations (UK)
I have a home EV Charge Point I am not currently using to charge a vehicle. I want to be able to use it as an outside power source for an electric mower or to power outside Christmas lights. Is this possible? I have seen an adapter which will convert a Type 2 charge socket into a UK 3 pin plug socket, but that was specifically sold as still being used for EV charging not general outside power use.

It may violate some code or law, but electrically your Type 2 will just output 240 V AC so they would light up. Have you tried it?

@winny, not yet the adapter costs £77 so I wanted to get more info first if possible

Electrically yes. Legally not sure.

if the adapter i 77 quids I urge you to call a few local electricians. I believe you can get the full work done for about the same price - I would do it myself and total in materials is around 10 euros.

Using the adapter is almost certainly not an issue. While a type 2 charge socket has some additional pins, to signal to the charger that a car is being connected, I expect such an adapter to tell the charger some basic stuff, so that power is available at the 3 pin socket - you mention a plug but I think (hope) it is actually a socket.
That said, the best long term solution would be to have an electrician install a standard socket right next to your charger socket. Odds are that the circuit that powers the wall charger can power also a standard socket. Perhaps a power limiting device might be needed, and even an RCD though I believe in the UK those are built in in all the sockets.

Yes 'socket', I will correct, thanks

@vladamir I'm not 100% sure but I think it's on  a completely separate supply coming direct from the meter into a mini switch-box with an RCD and a spare slot (where I currently have it switched off), and then about 30 feet of chunky cable to the charge point by the front door.  The spare slot on the switch-box means I guess the best solution is to wire in an outside socket to that so it's all separately fused and protected as you suggested.

Ultimately "get an electrician to install a socket" is the only safe answer IMO. I wouldn't expect the RCD to be in the socket, usually, it's in the circuit breaker, so it might be a problem if the charger is on a circuit without one, or if the charging circuit has some other specific conflicting regs - but if that was the case an electrician can figure that out. It might also be an easy enough job just to add a socket from the usual downstairs ring.
